# Intercept and change SQL on TableAdapter

Tags: c#, sql, dataset, tableadapter

We have a Dataset with about 40 TableAdapters on it. These are used everywhere in several hundred differnt projects.

To add a layer of security I now have the requirement to add some paramaters to all the queries on all the TableAdapters in the Dataset.

Is there a way I can intercept all queries and add the paramater so I do not need to update all the code using the table adapters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is doubtful that you will be able to do this. You **might** be able to use some the [Policy Injection Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ff632023.aspx) to assist but it is a stretch. Here is the overview from MSDN.

> ... application block can be used to implement interception policies to streamline the implementation of common features, such as logging, caching, exception handling, and validation, across a system.